# Centering 2 text elements on top of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center these 2 text elements but having trouble. I have no trouble centering both elements just using `text-align:center;`, but I actually want the sub-heading and heading to both start from the same point. So it should look sort of like this below, where the heading text is directly in the center. I hope I've made myself clear, I can provide a picture if necessary.

I should mention that these divs are responsive, so it would have to apply to any size not just "put left: 50%" or something like that :P

```
            sub-heading
            heading text here


<div>
  <img class="center-block" src="img/shop-1.jpg">
  <span>
    <p class="sub-heading">sub-heading</p>
    <p class="heading">heading text here</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.shop span {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 30%; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
}

.shop span p {
    padding: 0;
}

.shop span .heading {
    color: #fafafa;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #ecd781, 0 0 20px #ecd781, 0 0 40px #ecd781, 0 0 80px #ecd781;
    /*text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ecd781;*/
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Comment: Currently your CSS doesn't appear to match your HTML; the `shop` class is not present on any element so none of the rules will take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `.shop span` CSS as follows:

```
.shop span {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 30%; 
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will cause it to be centered based on the largest of the two headings.  (If `sub-heading` is *wider* than `heading`, this won't meet your requirement.)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wfxxw522/)

Comment: I don't think the transform is being applied on the mobile device I am testing on, any idea how to make the transform function there? The text just seems to have the `left: 50%;` applied to it

Answer (score 1):

You may wrap text with an extra `div` with the following styling:

```
display:inline-block; text-align:left
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/Nargus/pen/jEgVMb

Wrapper element will be centered by outer text-align:center; rule, but inside it you'll have text-align:left;
It is a much better way than fixed width and margin:auto; for centering

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both inside an `<div>` and than use following CSS for the `<div>`

```
div {
    width: 250px; /* Or the maximum of the wides text */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will position the div into the center, but let the text be left sided. If the width of the `<div>` is only max width of the wides text, it should fit.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xLgxsme7/

*edit*

If you want to use your `<span>` than you have to make it `display: block;`, because you can't change the width of an inline-element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried positioning your P classes using relative? It could work.

PS: your img tag isn't closed, insert / before >

Comment: I think this would be better served as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: If you using HTML5 you don't have to close it, actually you _shouldn't_ close it.

Comment: Since im below 50 rep I can't write comments (to not my posts). Just wanted to point out the missing / in case of further site validation. Sorry.

Comment: @Dashovsky No worries, although it's probably best to wait until you have enough rep otherwise you run the risk of getting downvoted and being further away from being able to comment! ;)

Comment: @HiddenHobbes it is quite annoying not being able to comment. I only got the right 2 or 3 days ago.

Comment: well yeah sometimes I would like to leave that small tip but I just can't do it since lots of people don't even mark my answer as correct after solving their case

Comment: @Tobsta I agree, especially as you only want to help but I guess the rule is there to stop comments being abused.

Comment: The `<img>` **element** is self-closing in HTML. The slash is redundant in HTML5 and an error in HTML4. There are other problems with the HTML worth pointing out, though.